# Understanding Deployment and contract design for BSC and pancakeswap

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, bsc, pancakeswap

I understand that for the Ethereum Mainnet you need to create an ERC20 Token
and for BSC you need a BEP20 Token.

Let's say I want to create a simple smart contract and deploy it on **Pancakeswap**.
In order to educate myself, I took the liberty to study the latest Hot Token: #FLOKI
Here is the source code for it:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x2B3F34e9D4b127797CE6244Ea341a83733ddd6E4#code

As you can see the Token uses the **ERC20 standard** but is deployed to the BSC and still somehow it recognize it as BEP20:
[image]

I have a few questions in regards to that topic hope you can help me with some:

1. Why the contract is deployed with the **ERC20 standard** and not **BEP20 standard** as it should, and why does BSC recognize it as BEP20?
2. I know from the docs that **Pancakeswap** uses **UniswapV2**, does this mean that in order for my token to work on Pancakeswap I need to implement Uniswap functionality in my contract just like in FLOKI, or a simple BEP20 will suffice?

That's all for now, many thanks to everyone that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

From [BEP20 documentation](https://docs.binance.org/faq/bsc/bep.html#what-is-bep20)

> What is BEP20?
>
> A token protocol on BSC which is compatible with BEP2 and ERC20. It extends ERC20 and contains more interfaces, such as getOwner and decimals.

BEP-20 compliant doesn't require any support for Pancakeswap.

Comment: So basically if I upload an ERC20 with Uniswap interface to BSC it should work the same if I uploaded BEP20 with Pancakeswap interface, the names don't matter?

Comment: @NikoKonovalov To be ERC-20 or BEP-20 compliant it is not necessary to support an dex like uniswap or pancake swap. Some tokens to provide extra incentives like staking, minting, burning when using an official pool, in that case they are integrated to a dex like pancakeswap. If you want to support pancakeswap then it is better to use their contracts instead of the uniswap ones.